# Flutter: How to send data to the server with what percentage of progress using HttpClient

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to send fairly large data to the server with what percentage of progress, but it fails. But when I send data without progress it works. Is it possible to get progress when sending data to server?
Here's the code I use. Please help thank you

```
void postDataWithProgress() async {
  HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
  var url = "https://xxxxxxx/api/adddata";
  HttpClientRequest request =
      await httpClient.postUrl(Uri.parse(url)).timeout(Duration(seconds: 10));

  var datavalue = {
    "listvideoname": ["a", "b", "c"],
    "listvideobase64": ["adahd", "ayuiary", "oukjfjka"]
  };
  var body = json.encode(datavalue);
  int byteCount = 0;
  var totalByteLength = body.length;

  Stream<String> mystream = new Stream.value(body);
  Stream<List<int>> streamUpload =
      mystream.transform(new StreamTransformer.fromHandlers(
    handleData: (data, sink) {
      byteCount += data.length;
    },
    handleDone: (sink) {
      sink.close();
    },
    handleError: (error, stackTrace, sink) {
      throw error;
    },
  ));
  request.contentLength = totalByteLength;
  request.addStream(streamUpload);

  request.headers
      .set("Content-Type", "application/json", preserveHeaderCase: true);
  request.headers
      .set("Authorization", "Bearer $token", preserveHeaderCase: true);

  request.add(utf8.encode(body));
  HttpClientResponse response = await request.close();
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    print("add data success");
  }else{
    print("add data error");
  }
}
```

Comment: `int cnt = 0;
final stream = File('someFile').openRead()
.map((event) {
cnt += event.length;
print('client cnt: $cnt');
return event;
});
final uri = Uri.parse('http://localhost:8080/foo');
await HttpClient().putUrl(uri)
.then((request) => request.addStream(stream))
.then((request) => request.close());
`

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i'm not using the File

Comment: it does not matter, you need a `Stream` - i used a `File` just to test it on large data - you can replace `File('someFile').openRead()` with any kind of `Stream<List<int>>`

Comment: for example: `final foobar = [{'id': 10, 'name': 'foo'}, {'id': 11, 'name': 'bar'}] as dynamic;
final stream = Stream.value(foobar)
.transform(json.fuse(utf8).encoder)
.map((event) {
cnt += event.length;
print('client cnt: $cnt');
return event;
});`

Comment: I tried this and the byteCount looks but the app crashes and fails to send to the server

final valbody = body as dynamic;

  final mystream =
      new Stream.value(valbody).transform(json.fuse(utf8).encoder).map((event) {
    byteCount += event.length;
    print('client cnt: $byteCount');
  });

request.addStream(mystream);
request.add(utf8.encode(body));